# The page isn't redirecting properly in Servlet/Filter

Tags: java, redirect, servlets

I am new to Servlet and Filter. I am trying to block all users that is not logged-in in my application.

**Web.xml file**

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>UserFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>user.UserFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>avoid-urls</param-name>
        <param-value>index.jsp, SelectDb.jsp, login.jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>

    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UserFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**The Filter Class**

```
package user;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


public class UserFilter implements Filter {

    private ArrayList<String> urlList;

    public UserFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        String url = request.getServletPath();
        String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
        boolean allowedRequest = false;

        for (String urlList1 : urlList) {
            if (url.contains(urlList1)) {
                allowedRequest = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!allowedRequest) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            if (null == session) {
                response.sendRedirect("");
            } else {
                String logged = (String) session.getAttribute("username");
                if (logged == null) {
                    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/dashboard/SelectDb.jsp");
                } else {
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
            }
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) {
        String urls = config.getInitParameter("avoid-urls");
        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(urls, ",");
        urlList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
            urlList.add(token.nextToken());
        }
    }

}
```

I can see that the page is redirecting properly to the page I want to redirect. The Url is changing. But the `Firefox` says that the page is not redirecting properly. The Message is somewhat like this: `Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies`. I do not think that this error is from the browser itself. Because I've tried other browser also. Why this error ? How can Solve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

to

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
```

`request.getSession()` will create a new session if there is no session yet, so it will never return null, thus the user is redirected to the selectDb url where he has `!allowedRequest` and its enters and infinite redirection